# Identify unused application pools

Tags: powershell, iis

I intend to find out the unused application pools among tens of live app pools on each server in a web farm containing a number of servers. The app pools are isolated per website and application.

I have listed out the application pools per server using a PS script - I'm a newbie btw, however I'm unable to match the IIS logs against the website ID for the corresponding application pool to determine if any traffic is served by the website/application at all.

This is mainly for housekeeping reasons. Is there any better approach I can take to automate the entire process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would think this would be easier--perhaps there is an easier way, but the following is what I was able to come up with.  I have never used PowerShell to manage IIS so it's likely that someone who has more expertise in the area will have a more concise approach.

```
import-module WebAdministration

# get a list of the application pools
$pools = dir IIS:\AppPools

# iterate through the pools and find the ones that are not used by any websites
foreach($pool in $pools){

    if ((Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool='$($pool.name)']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).Count -eq 0)
        {
             write-host $pool.name "has no websites."
        }
}
```

Comment: That's given me the information I was looking for. Thanks.